# tcpdf Error: requires GD or Imagik but I installed the dependencies

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, composer-php, tcpdf

I setting up a web server on AWS ec2 with LAMP stack and I installed all the dependencies to compose works but when I tried to see a PDF the server give me the Error: TCPDF ERROR: TCPDF requires the Imagick or GD extension to handle PNG images with alpha channel.

Well since yesterday I tried to solve the problem with the options provide for the community

1. Adding the extension on the `php.ini`
2. Restart Apache
3. Recompile PHP

When I run `php -i` I see the libraries but It doesn't works:

I expect to see the PDF but I received the Error described or the Error 500

Comment: If you run `php -m` do you see the `GD` module in the list?

Comment: Yes this is the list of modules: 
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

Comment: The configuration for PHP used on the CLI can differ from the one used when accessed through the web server. You can use the `phpinfo()` function to check how the config looks like when accessing your application through HTTP. It will also tell you where the `php.ini` file(s) are located.

Comment: @xabbuh [php.config](https://i.gyazo.com/aadae2677f7236c398064b4b8a546303.png) This is the information of phpinfo() I edit the php.ini file and the gd.ini file it's located in the dir /etc/php.d but is not detected by the config. In addition this is the GD section of my php.ini [GD section](https://i.gyazo.com/cedde3b989f5da8124db35fb8fd21cef.png)

Comment: @xabbuh and this my dir [/etc/php.d](https://i.gyazo.com/bf27b06fb0eb05580814d1b44e9f0aa2.png)